# How to select only matching records from mongodb document having an array of objects in spring version

Tags: mongodb

I have a document as below in my sample collection

```json
  {
    _id: 1,
    "name": "NA",
    request_address: [
      {
        "state": "kyz",
        "city": "abc",
        "housenbr": [
          "123",
          "345",
          "456"
        ]
      },
      {
        "state": "pqr",
        "city": "def",
        "housenbr": [
          "898",
          "765"
        ]
      },
      {
        "state": "wrt",
        "city": "zdc"
      }
    ]
  }
```

when I use

```
db.sample.find({_id:1},{request_address:{$elemMatch:{state:"pqr"}}})
```

I am having only the below data which is as expected

```json
  {
    _id: 1,
    request_address: [
      {
        "state": "pqr",
        "city": "def",
        "housenbr": [
          "898",
          "765"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

but when I use this in the spring version

Query query = new Query;

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(1));

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("request_address").elemMatch(Criteria.where("state").is("PR)));

mongoConfiguration.mongoTemplate().findOne(query, sampleEntity.class)

 I am having an error No property request found for type sampleEntity.class.
```

what is the wrong I am doing can you provide the details

Comment: The part `{request_address:{$elemMatch:{state:"pqr"}}}` is a projection, but you are adding a `where` clause in java for it

Comment: ok can you let me know how to add projection in spring

Comment: You can try something along these lines:
    `Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(1));
    query.fields().project(MongoExpression.create("{request_address:{$elemMatch:{state:\"pqr\"}}}"));`

Comment: do we need to import any external lib for project and MongoExpression, I am not having those options at all. when I provide fields I have below options "position asking for string) and also include that also need to have string

Comment: Nope, I am getting that in spring data library itself. These are the imports, that I have
`import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoExpression;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;`